# Variable 'lat' has conflicting _FillValue (nan) and missing_value (-9999.0). Cannot encode data

Tags: python-xarray

I tried to save an `xr.dataset` by running, for example:

`ds.to_netcdf('save/directory/filename.nc')`

and got an error:

`Variable 'lat' has conflicting _FillValue (nan) and missing_value (-9999.0). Cannot encode data.`

How would I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Those are probably attributes. You can view a variable's attributes with `ds.lat.attrs`.

You can directly modify the attributes by accessing the elements of the attributes like a dictionary:

```py
ds.lat.attrs['missing_value'] = np.nan
```

or by dropping one of them

```py
del ds.lat.attrs['_FillValue']
```

If your *data* actually has both NaNs and -9999 as a fill value and you'd like to just go with one, you could also mask the data. I'm guessing -9999 was selected for use with integer data?

For integer data, `NaN` is not an option, so we'll stick with -9999, and coerce to 32-bit integers as an example:

```py
ds['lat'] = ds['lat'].where(pd.notnull(ds['lat']), -9999).astype('int32')
```

For floats, we could stick with `np.nan`:

```py
ds['lat'] = ds['lat'].where(ds['lat'] != -9999)
```

Comment: Thank you, but sorry I cannot reproduce the error so I am not sure your suggestion can solve my problem. I will revisit later when I meet the same problem.

Comment: ok. if you can't reproduce the error to confirm whether this is helpful, then this isn't a useful question for the site. See this guide to help produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for some great tips for next time!

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will keep it in mind!